# PHP / SQL give rest of users a value

Tags: php, sql, select, foreach, phpmyadmin

What I did was to give 2 users in my `DB` a `categorie_bit` value of `1`,
When I click on a button. That works so far. Now I am trying to give the rest of the user a `categorie_bit` value of `0`, if I click on that button.

So basically:

Give 2 Random `Users` `categorie_bit` value `1` & Give Rest of the `User` in `DB` `categorie_bit` value of `0`.

(Again giving 2 random Users value of 1 works and saves in db.)

I tried this so far to give the rest a value of 0:

```
    $member  = $staff->getStaffData($id);
    $queryCheck = $database->query('SELECT id,firstname,lastname,categorie_bit FROM `staff` WHERE categorie_bit = 1');
    $queryCheckResult = $queryCheck->fetch();
    $queryMaximum = $queryCheckResult > 1;

    var_dump($queryMaximum); // true

    // MY SQL TO GIVE REST A VALUE OF 0 
    $taste = $database->query('SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM `staff` WHERE categorie_bit = 1 SET categorie_bit = 0');
    if($queryMaximum) {
        echo "first step works";
        if(is_array($taste) || is_object($taste)) {
            echo "second step works";
            foreach ($taste as $testx) {
                var_dump($testx);
            }
        } else {
            echo "second does not work";
        }
    }
```

This did not work. I always get the echo of `second does not work`.

Can anyone help me:)

Comment: `$taste` is probably returning `false`. You're probably wanting an `UPDATE` SQL statement.

Comment: You have to use `UPDATE` instead of `SELECT` if you want to update records in database.

Comment: As you have written a wrong `query` i.e `select` and `update` in a single statement its not returning anything in your `$taste`,  so `$taste` is not a `array` or `object` its always echo `second does not work`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request you perform is wrong. 
Either you make a select to retrieve user or you make an update to update user.

If you replace

```
'SELECT id,firstname,lastname FROM `staff` WHERE categorie_bit = 1 SET categorie_bit = 0'
```

With :

```
"UPDATE staff SET categorie_bit = 0 where categorie_bit = 1"
```

Your data should be updated ;)

Answer (score 1):

you have used `SET` in `SELECT` statement which can be used in `UPDATE` query. Be specific on what you want to query from DB. If you want to update all records with `category_bit = 0` then

```
$taste = $database->query('UPDATE `staff` SET categorie_bit = 0 where categorie_bit = 1');
```